# How can we populate the default shipping address country and zipcode in cart page in magento 2 for logged in customers?

Tags: magento2, xml, customer-account, knockoutjs, shipping-tax

Can we populate the default country and postcode for the logged in users using their default shipping address of the customer to get shipping estimates?

Answer (score 1):

You can create Block in your Custom module and call method **getShipping()** 
 to get all data of Shipping address from your phtml file as below:

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Shipping extends Template
{

    protected $_addressFactory;
    protected $customerSession;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
    ) {

            $this->_addressFactory = $addressFactory;
            $this->customerSession = $customerSession->create();
            parent::__construct($context);
    }



    public function getShipping() {
        //get customer model before you can get its address data

        if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) { 
         $shippingAddressId=$this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping();
         $shippingAddress = $this->_addressFactory->create()->load($shippingAddressId);
         $shippingdata= $shippingAddress->getData();

         return $shippingdata;
        }
        else
        {
            return '';
        }
     }
}
```

You can call it in Template(.phtml) file as below:

```
$shippingblock=$block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Shipping');
$shippingAddress=$shippingblock->getShipping();
```

Comment: In order to populate this xml layout files,do we need to write a js as intermediate step?or directly can we populate this data to xml item attributes?

Comment: No need to write js. You can simply call this block method in any template file(.phtml) file.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check.